# Printing out letters from array

Tags: c

I tried many things but I just cant find any solution to the problem. I am trying to print the contents of an array one by one but it crashes. How can I make each index corresponding letter print out after each iteration?

```
main() {
   int i;
   char myArray[10];

   for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    myArray[i] = "a";
    printf("%s\n", myArray[i]);
   }

}
```

I also tried:

```
printf("%c\n", myArray[i])
```

and:

```
printf("%d\n", (int)myArray[i]) gives me the numbers 36.
```

Comment: You're using the %s (string) format specifier to print a character - tryn printf("%c\n", myArray[i]);

Comment: Also, you're assigning a string to a single char using "" double quotes, try single quotes for a sngle character - myArray[i] = 'a';

Comment: What is the `arr[i]`? I don't see an `arr` declared (or initialized) anywhere.

Comment: @e0k will edit, sorry. Hang on

Comment: You never initialized your myArray.  arr is undefined.

Comment: @Nunchy it works thanks : ) please post your answer

Comment: Also, did you know you are only iterating through 5, but declared for 10?

Comment: That's alright mate just happy to be helpful. Have fun with your coding ;)

Comment: @Nunchy Thanks my friend and wish you a fun time as well : )

Comment: @e0k thanks for making me notice. Ya, I need some sleep hehe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of completion, I felt obligated to point out that even `return 0;` isn't quite official, as I'll demonstrate below.

> Also, did you know you are only iterating through 5, but declared for 10?
>
> -e0k
>
> @e0k thanks for making me notice. Ya, I need some sleep hehe
>
> -Asperger

In order for you to remember to iterate through the same amount of indices as you declared in your array, you should `#define` your array length like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE 10

int main(void) // we're not using argc and argv
{
    size_t i; // use size_t since i is used as an array index
    char myArray[ARRAY_SIZE];

    for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++) 
    {
        myArray[i] = 'a';
        printf("%c\n", myArray[i]);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS; // defined in stdlib.h
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. `arr` is array with elements of type `char` - you should assign 'a' to each element instead of "a" (the latter gives you some address in memory - namely address where "a" is stored).
2. `%s` is used to print null terminated string. Use `%c` instead due to type of elements in your array.

PS. Better use main like this:

```
int main(void)
{
  ...
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: you can remove the arr part. I changed the name and forgot to edit that one too. Corrected already

Answer (score 2):

1. Your main function doesn't have a return value. You need to use either int or void.
2. `arr[i] = "a";` assigns a null-terminated string to `arr[i]`, you want to assign a char.
3. What is `arr`? The name of your array is `myArray`!
4. `printf("%s\n", myArray[i]);` will interpret `myArray[i]` as a string, but it is a char.

This is the corrected program:

```
int main() 
{
    int i;
    char myArray[10];

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
    {
        myArray[i] = 'a';
        printf("%c\n", myArray[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: It works when I do   myArray[i] = 'a'; printf("%c\n", myArray[i]);

Comment: Ok, my compiler also allows me to leave out the return value, however you really should add the return value to main, otherwise it's very ugly

Comment: Yes, this as well. But also `int main() { [...] }` or `void main() { [...] }`